# Remove 'EFI File Boot 0' from boot options / priority

Tags: boot, uefi

I have an acer laptop (originally came with Windows) with InsydeH20 Setup Utility as the F2 menu. As a newb to Linux, I installed Ubuntu Desktop and I regretted adding disk encryption and I figured out quickly that it wasn't easy, so I just wiped the drive. I set it up and had to add a 'Trusted UEFI file to execute' with F2 by adding `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` as `UbuntuFS`.

Now, when I press F2 and navigate to 'Boot', I see an entry for my old Ubuntu FS as `EFI File Boot 0: UbuntuFS`. I'd like to remove that.

I have seen two answers already telling me to use a USB or CD to use Terminal and `sudo efibootmgr -b x -B` and it will NOT go away. I installed Ubuntu a second time and tried setting the UEFI Trusted file (what I did the first time) but it said 'Boot Description is exist'. It actually showed two options, one named `ubuntu` and `UbuntuFS` so I removed both. Using F12 to boot onto 'UbuntuFS' also says there's nothing to boot to.

So, **can I reset my BIOS or UEFI to at least reset or preferably remove the boot priority to remove 'UbuntuFS' from my boot list?** Boot mode is UEFI and Secure Boot is on. The EFI File appears as the last option in priority. Currently, the laptop is in an unusable state and only has access to my bootable USB, bios menu, and has an EFI option for a OS that is no longer on my HDD.

I have seen:

- https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/proliant_uefi/UEFI_Edgeline_103117/s_deleting_boot_option.html (What is this referring to?)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/63613 (Tried, did not remove option from F2 menu. Also have seen many other answers based around `efibootmgr`)

I have wasted time with:

- Removing the CMOS and Laptop battery to wipe BIOS (doesn't do anything) (Attempt to wipe boot options)
- Running between Windows 10 and Linux install USBs to delete 'EFI/ubuntu' (still shows up on F2)
- Tried 'bcdedit /enum' and 'bcdedit /delete' on Windows 10
- Wiped the entire HDD clean using GParted on a Linux USB, including the EFI partition
- About to try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlcCid841WU)...

Please tell me that there's something EASY for this, I've sunk way too much time figuring this out with no avail.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo efibootmgr` ? ([Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422447/edit) your question and add the output).

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/what-is-acer-boot-menu-how-to-acces-change.html

Comment: efibootmgr initially showed `ubuntu` and `UbuntuFS`, so I removed both. Then after running the instructions from the linked AU post and going back to the F2 menu and back into Linux it shows `ubuntu`.

Comment: That is correct, then. `ubuntu` is the entry for your current OS.

Comment: i reinstalled ubuntu for a third time and I can definitely NOT get in. Setting it as the trusted UEFI executable file through setup utility says 'file is exist' and won't let me create another entry.

Comment: I managed to get into my drive, by using the USB installer and hitting 'boot next volume' until I got past a security boot fail warning. Tried `sudo efibootmgr` and still got `UbuntuFS`. Repeated this process twice and I still see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Setup Utility, or the F2 menu, there WAS an option that wiped the EFI File list.

Under Security is `Erase all Secure Boot Setting` and `Restore Secure Boot to Factory Default`. I'm pretty sure I enabled both options and immediately exited because it did nothing to the boot order.

All I had to do was to hit those two options, then save. Next time I opened up the F2 menu, `UbuntuFS` was gone.